# Qt Consuming WebService

Tags: web-services, qt, webservice-client

Can any one provide me a simple example on how to consume a webservice using Qt C++ ?

Answer (score -1):

This helped me out, got it working over 2 computers as well, one being the host, the other the client.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wbhsy70(v=VS.100).aspx